# Function running twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function written down in a different file and imported into the point where I need it in the main code. However, when I run it the text in the function is being run twice. I don't know why it's happening.

```
def poor():
    print("\n")
    print("\n")
    print("You wake up under a bridge, it is raining you're cold")
    print("You look around you, no one seems to be there under the bridge except you.")
    print("Above you, it is bustling")


poor()
```

And this is the function which I've imported

```
            path = input(c)
            if path.lower().strip() == "yes":
                print(sb)
                from tests import poor
                poor() #Where I call the function
```

So this is where I call the function

```
So be it




You wake up under a bridge, it is raining you're cold
You look around you, no one seems to be there under the bridge except you.
Above you, it is bustling




You wake up under a bridge, it is raining you're cold
You look around you, no one seems to be there under the bridge except you.
Above you, it is bustling
```

And this is the end result when I run the code, it is repeating for some reason.

My goal is to basically write an entire scenario within the function and call it when needed and not have the function run twice

Comment: Please post all the relevant code. Clearly, the function is called from some code that isn't shown. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: poor() is called once when the module is imported (since you have called poor() in the module being imported) and once from the main module.

Comment: There are two places where you have written poor(), one in the main file from where you are calling and second in the file where poor is written. I guess if you paste the exact code than it is more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `poor()` is being called in the last line of your module `tests`. This gets executed when you do the `import`. If you remove that last line, it will work as desired.

For testing purposes it is often convenient to have the function in the end like this

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    poor()
```

That way, if you execute `tests.py` from the cli, `poor()` gets called, whereas if you `import tests`, it does not.